# how to filter pandas data frame more efficiently

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which I need to select on the ts column many times. The selection is performed like  `df[df['ts'] >= ... & df['ts'] <= ...]`.

```
ts               val
1494890360      0.02
1494890381      0.01
1494890386      -1.05
......
```

now it seems this selection had became the bottle neck of my application. So is there a way to make this selection more efficient? I can do as much preprocessing as possible because the df is just created once and then will be queried for millions of times.

Comment: Is `ts` sorted and the index?

Comment: try to use `numexpr` or `df.query`, long `numpy`/`pandas` expressions like `S OP S OP S` where `OP` are vectorized operations on `pandas` or `numpy` container `S`, then there is an intermediate container created for every binary operation.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I can make it sorted and set it to index.

Comment: `df.query(f'ts >= {lower_bound} and ts <= {upper_bound}')`

Comment: hm... tried to use query, but seems not helping.